# How to change External IP of a Google Cloud VM instance to my 'normal' IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I'd firstly like to point out that I am not an expert with computers, so if I ask any nonsensical questions, then I would hope that you would forgive me!

I have lately been using the Google cloud virtual machines. I am unsure why, but they are a lot faster than the virtual machines that I install with VirtualBox. So I have been using Google cloud virtual machines to play browser games where computer and internet speed is important. However, the browser game that I play does not permit the use of proxies/VPNs. So I quickly get banned when a Human does a manual review of my account, because these virtual machines give one of googles proxies.

**So I would like to find a solution for this. Would it be possible to somehow change the virtual machine's IP to the IP that my host operating system uses?**

If this is not possible, then I would appreciate if anyone could brainstorm some alternative solutions. I have thought about Residential proxies, as these proxies cannot be detected when site owners run it in one of those websites that reveal datacenter proxy users. But, these proxies cost a bit too much.

I have one final question. **Why are these Google cloud virtual machines so fast in comparison to virtual machines that are manually installed?**

Comment: *"I quickly get banned when a Human does a manual review of my account, because these virtual machines give one of googles proxies."*  I don't think that's quite accurate.  There is no proxy.  It's a *Google IP address*, which they are *incorrectly* interpreting as "it must be a proxy" (or VPN) on the assumption that your computer isn't really at Google.  The problem with that logic is is... your computer -- the one where you are playing the game -- technically *is* at Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a VM without specific IP, called static IP, simply restarted the VM (perform stop and start, not a reset). The ephemeral IP will change.

Then, about speed, it's hard to answer without knowing exactly the other VM that you speak about. VMs, with the same CPU and memory, are globally equivalent. However, localisation and network can change. Google have a great network with low latency